# Do the words used to transform into a Magical Garment Girl actually mean anything?

Tags: japanese-language, kore-wa-zombie-desu-ka

In *Kore Wa Zombie Desu Ka* (Is This A Zombie?), whenever one wants to transform into a magical girl, he says the following words:

> Nomobuyo, Oshi, Hashitawa, Dokeda, Gunmicha, De, Ribura!

[image: the magic incantation]

Do those words have any real meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading this backwards (in Japanese, so by reversing the morae rather than the romanized letters) gives you "raburii de chaamingu dakedo watashi wa shi wo yobu mono" (ラブリーでチャーミングだけど私は死を呼ぶもの), which means "lovely and charming though I am, I am he who summons death".